# Area of infinite number of squares inside triangle

Tags: proof-verification

[image: CSAT Sample Paper 3]

This question is from the third sample paper for the CSAT (Computer Science Admissions Test) at Cambridge. My working is as follows:

First, I worked out the equation of the diagonal line touching the top right corner of each square as being:  $y+\frac{1}{a}x=1 \to ay+x=a$

I then worked out the x-coordinate of the intersection point between the diagonal and the top right corner of the first square. I did this using simultaneous equations with the square's diagonal which is clearly $y=x$

$$ay+x=a$$ 
$$y=x$$
Sub in:
$$ax+x=a$$
$$x(a+1)=a$$
$$x_1=\frac{a}{a+1}$$
Then clearly the area of the first square  $A_1 = (\frac{a}{a+1})^2$

I then did the exact same thing to work out the top right corner of the second square. I used the equation $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ to work out the equation of the diagonal of the second square as $y=x-\frac{a}{a+1}$. Again I did simultaneous equations as follows:

$$ay+x=a$$
$$y=x-\frac{a}{a+1}$$
Sub in:
$$a(x-\frac{a}{a+1})+x=a$$
$$ax-\frac{a^2}{a+1}+x=a$$
$$ax+x=a+\frac{a^2}{a+1}$$
$$x(a+1)=\frac{2a^2+a}{a+1}$$
$$x_2=\frac{a(2a+1)}{(a+1)^2}$$

Then, to work out the length of the second square, I did $x_2-x_1$ which yielded $(\frac{a}{a+1})^2$. I then saw a pattern between the two lengths so I repeated the working for the third fraction and the pattern held. The pattern I found is that the length of the square is always $(\frac{a}{a+1})^n$ and so the area of each square is $(\frac{a}{a+1})^{2n}$.

$\therefore$ the total area is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{a}{a+1})^{2n}$

I have 2 questions:

1. Is my working correct?
2. Are there any better/more efficient ways of doing this? (I'm pre-calculus and haven't learnt summations etc.)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown has a nice answer. Yours may in fact agree with his after you sum the geometric series you found. (I haven't checked.)

Comment: @EthanBolker Ah yes they are equal. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the left-most trapezium. It consists of a square of sidelength
$h$, say, surmounted by a right-angled triangle whose legs must measure
$h$ and $h/a$. Therefore $h+h/a=1$, that is $h=a/(1+a)$. The area
of the trapezium is $(h/2)(h+1)$, and so the proportion of its area
contained in the square is
$$\frac{h^2}{(h/2)(h+1)}=\frac{2h}{h+1}=\frac{2a}{1+2a}.$$
But that is the proportion of the **whole** triangle occupied by the
squares. The squares' area must add up to
$$\frac{2a}{1+2a}\frac{a}{2}=\frac{a^2}{1+2a}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand all of that. I did actually think about using the trapezium at the beginning but decided against it :-( But where's the mistake in my working then?

Comment: Very nice way to avoid having to sum a geometric series

Comment: @dan Your summation should be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a/(1+a))^{2n}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yep sorry. I copied my working wrong.